# Help connecting to Windows Shares on 2003/2008 server Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows, nautilus

Can anyone help me , I'm really struggling to connect to Windows shares via Nautilus using the Connect to server command - anyone know the correct Syntax to use for user names and domain names or work groups?

Its driving me nuts, I would fully use Ubuntu for work if I could make it connect to my Windows 2003/2008/ Windows 7 shares/ File servers seamlessly.

How do you do it? I have been googling my a$%S off but can't work it out

[image: connect]

I have no issues with SSH or FTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using "connect to server" you could try opening a nautilus window, press CTRL+L to show address bar, and write the address of your shared folder in this way:

```
smb://10.10.10.11/GLOBAL
```

Pressing enter you'll be asked for user, domain and password for the connection.
If you have trouble connecting using the domain name written in capital letter, try lower-case.
Til now I've been able to connect to every Windows Server I met

Comment: Thanks Lupp0l0 - After I wrote the question out I cracked it after a 4 hours of trying - ![image](http://i13.photobucket.com/albums/a260/hellboy660/connect-fixed.jpg) - really annoying as in the help with ubuntu it assumes that you know what the syntax is - not helpful if you have come from a windows environment that users \\servername\C$ -  the fact that the connect window already asks for the Domain that you log into , why would I think I would have to use username@domainname.int as its already asked in the "domain" section! Thanks for the help - hope this helps others!

Comment: also added this - ------------------ SOLUTION ------------------------
in /etc/samba/smb.conf add the following to the bottom of the [global]
section:

client lanman auth = yes
client ntlmv2 auth = no
----------------------------